# An almost potential game

Tags: game-theory

$\def\argmax{\mathop{\rm argmax}}$

Recall that *potential games* are non-cooperative games that allow for a potential function that behaves in a sense "similarly" as the pay-off functions. Inspired by a certain class of optimization algorithms, I met a game that is "almost" potential. It is defined as follows. There are $n$ players. Player $i$ has the  strategy set $S_i$ and pay-off function $f_i: S\to\mathbb{R}$, where $S=S_1\times\cdots\times S_n$. There is a potential function $F: S\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $x\in S$ and $x'_i\in S_i$, the following three conditions hold:

- $f_i(x)-f_i(x'_i,x_{-i})\ge0\;\Longrightarrow\;F(x)-F(x'_i,x_{-i})\ge0$
- $F(x)-F(x'_i,x_{-i})>0\;\Longrightarrow\;f_i(x)-f_i(x'_i,x_{-i})>0$
- $\displaystyle\argmax_{x_i\in S_i}f_i(x)\subseteq\argmax_{x_i\in S_i}F(x)$

where for $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in S$ we denoted $x_{-i}=(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$, and $\argmax$ is the set of *all* maximisers.

Note that the game is similar to (but not contained in) two known classes of games:

1. *generalized ordinal potential games*, defined by $f_i(x)-f_i(x'_i,x_{-i})>0\;\Longrightarrow\;F(x)-F(x'_i,x_{-i})>0$
2. *pseudo-potential games*, defined by $\displaystyle\argmax_{x_i\in S_i}f_i(x)\supseteq\argmax_{x_i\in S_i}F(x)$

It would help me to know if my game belongs to any known game class and if anything can be said about its pure Nash equilibria (perhaps under some assumptions on $S_i$, such as compactness). I googled a lot, but found nothing. Many thanks!

Tom

Comment: What is your game?